# CSS design - rainbow

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I want to create a rainbow using only CSS only. Below is an image of what is required.

[image]

Here is my code (so far):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#r {
  height: 80vw;
  width: 80vw;
  background-color: #f00;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
#o {
  height: 76vw;
  width: 76vw;
  background-color: #fe6230;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2vw;
  left: 2vw;
  z-index: 2;
}
#y {
  height: 72vw;
  width: 72vw;
  background-color: #fef600;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4vw;
  left: 4vw;
  z-index: 3;
}
#g {
  height: 68vw;
  width: 68vw;
  background-color: #00bc00;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6vw;
  left: 6vw;
  z-index: 4;
}
#b {
  height: 64vw;
  width: 64vw;
  background-color: #0048fe;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8vw;
  left: 8vw;
  z-index: 5;
}
#i {
  height: 60vw;
  width: 60vw;
  background-color: #000083;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10vw;
  left: 10vw;
  z-index: 6;
}
#v {
  height: 56vw;
  width: 56vw;
  background-color: #30009b;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12vw;
  left: 12vw;
  z-index: 7;
}
```

```html
<div id="r">
</div>
<div id="o">
</div>
<div id="y">
</div>
<div id="g">
</div>
<div id="b">
</div>
<div id="i">
</div>
<div id="v">
</div>
```

The problem with my code is that I am unable to curve it (like in a real rainbow). I also need to hide half of this rainbow.

Comment: Why dont you use box-shadow for pseudo element and with border-radius place and hide it with overflow hidden ?

Comment: related : [Overlapping circles in CSS with 1 div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27314373/overlapping-circles-in-css-with-1-div)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This could be done using a single `div` element with a :pseudo-element and `box-shadow`.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: scale(2);
  margin-left: 130px;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
div:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #4200AB, 0 0 0 10px #000095, 0 0 0 15px #00ABFF, 0 0 0 20px #00C800, 0 0 0 25px #FFF800, 0 0 0 30px #FF7642, 0 0 0 35px #E40000;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Example using `vh` / `vw` units.

<kbd>**[Demo on CodePen](http://codepen.io/chipChocolate/pen/OPbMrW)**</kbd>

Looks awful in the snippet here because of the viewport ratio, better viewed on CodePen.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 95vw;
  height: 45vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: transparent;
  transform: translate(-50vw, -16.666vw);
  top: 8vw;
  left: 50vw;
}
div:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 25vw;
  left: 25vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2vw #4200AB, 0 0 0 4vw #000095, 0 0 0 6vw #00ABFF, 0 0 0 8vw #00C800, 0 0 0 10vw #FFF800, 0 0 0 12vw #FF7642, 0 0 0 14vw #E40000;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Why is this so small?

Comment: @JakeMikail - I've made it big.

Comment: But can't we use vw units? It needs to change with changing width of the veiwport.

Comment: @JakeMikail - Check out the example that uses `vh`/`vw` units.

Comment: either use `vh` or `vw`! Maintain the ratio! Great Answer btw!

Comment: Great answer using shadow-box, cuts a lot of the duplicate divs out. 

Answer (score 7):

Here is a slightly different approach using `radial-gradient`. The approach is pretty much self explanatory as the gradient background is applied in an elliptical manner with multiple color stops (one for each color + white at the beginning and end).

**Note:** The [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient) is much better for `box-shadow` than it is for `radial-gradients` and hence the answer posted by chipChocolate.py is probably the best for now.

This one can also support vw/vh units and can adapt the appearance accordingly.

```css
.rainbow {
  height: 25vw;
  width: 50vw;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 110%, ellipse, white 35%, violet 35%, violet 40%, indigo 40%, indigo 45%, blue 45%, blue 50%, green 50%, green 55%, yellow 55%, yellow 60%, orange 60%, orange 65%, red 65%, red 70%, white 70%);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(50% 110%, ellipse, white 35%, violet 35%, violet 40%, indigo 40%, indigo 45%, blue 45%, blue 50%, green 50%, green 55%, yellow 55%, yellow 60%, orange 60%, orange 65%, red 65%, red 70%, white 70%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% 110%, white 35%, violet 35%, violet 40%, indigo 40%, indigo 45%, blue 45%, blue 50%, green 50%, green 55%, yellow 55%, yellow 60%, orange 60%, orange 65%, red 65%, red 70%, white 70%);
}
```

```html
<div class="rainbow"></div>
```

Comment: Use `vw` or `vh` for both `height` and `width` to maintain the 1:1 ratio

Comment: @ThePragmatick: You were too quick for me mate. I was just editing. Thanks though :)

Comment: Your's too is working fine. But its heavily aliased on Firefox 34.05?

Comment: @JakeMikail: Are you referring to the jagged edges? Unfortunately it tends to happen with radial gradients. That is another reason why this approach is better just kept for reference than for live implementation :)

Answer (score 4):

I thought i'd add just some of the rainbow designs found while going through codepen for your inspiration (**note** I did not make these, it's more for reference than anything)

## option 1

```css
@import "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Racing+Sans+One";
  
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    from {
      -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    to {
      -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

#rainbow {
  height: 290px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 580px;
  -moz-transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
  transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
}

#rainbow.reveal {
  height: 600px;
}

#rainbow li {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#rainbow .ribbon {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  left: inherit;
  top: inherit;
  -moz-animation: spin;
  -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation: spin;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation: spin;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#rainbow .red {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#rainbow .red .ribbon {
  border-color: red;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  clip: rect(0px, 580px, 290px, 0px);
  -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

#rainbow .orange {
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}

#rainbow .orange .ribbon {
  border-color: orange;
  height: 420px;
  width: 420px;
  clip: rect(0px, 500px, 250px, 0px);
  -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

#rainbow .yellow {
  left: 40px;
  top: 40px;
}

#rainbow .yellow .ribbon {
  border-color: yellow;
  height: 340px;
  width: 340px;
  clip: rect(0px, 420px, 210px, 0px);
  -moz-animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

#rainbow .green {
  left: 60px;
  top: 60px;
}

#rainbow .green .ribbon {
  border-color: green;
  height: 260px;
  width: 260px;
  clip: rect(0px, 340px, 170px, 0px);
  -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

#rainbow .blue {
  left: 80px;
  top: 80px;
}

#rainbow .blue .ribbon {
  border-color: blue;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  clip: rect(0px, 260px, 130px, 0px);
  -moz-animation-delay: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

#rainbow .indigo {
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
}

#rainbow .indigo .ribbon {
  border-color: indigo;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  clip: rect(0px, 180px, 90px, 0px);
  -moz-animation-delay: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
  animation-delay: 5s;
}

#rainbow .violet {
  left: 120px;
  top: 120px;
}

#rainbow .violet .ribbon {
  border-color: violet;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  clip: rect(0px, 100px, 50px, 0px);
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

.cta {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #622AF0;
  font-family: 'Racing Sans One', cursive;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

body {
  background: #DFFAFF;
}
```

```html
<ul id="rainbow">
  <li class="red">
    <strong class="ribbon">Red</strong>
  </li>
  <li class="orange">
    <strong class="ribbon">Orange</strong>
  </li>
  <li class="yellow">
    <strong class="ribbon">Yellow</strong>
  </li>
  <li class="green">
    <strong class="ribbon">Green</strong>
  </li>
  <li class="blue">
    <strong class="ribbon">Blue</strong>
  </li>
  <li class="indigo">
    <strong class="ribbon">Indigo</strong>
  </li>
  <li class="violet">
    <strong class="ribbon">Violet</strong>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

## option 2

```css
body {
   background-color: #A7BACB;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }
  
  html {
   position: relative;
   height: 100%;
   background: #F9FEFF;
  }
  .rainbow {
   width: 500px;
   height: 240px;
   margin: 20% auto 0 auto;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -250px;
   bottom:0;
  }
  .rainbow p {
   text-indent: -9000px;
   margin: 0;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 600px 560px;
   -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 600px 560px;
   -moz-border-radius-topleft: 600px 560px;
   -moz-border-radius-topright: 600px 560px;
  }
  .rainbow p:nth-child(1),
  .rainbow .r {
   background-color: #FF0000; /* red */
   height: 240px;
   width: 500px;
  }
  .rainbow p:nth-child(2),
  .rainbow .o { 
   background-color: #FF9900; /* orange */
   height: 220px;
   width: 460px;
   left: 20px;
  }
  .rainbow p:nth-child(3),
  .rainbow .y {
   background-color: #FFFF00; /* yellow */
   height: 200px;
   width: 420px;
   left: 40px;
  }
  .rainbow p:nth-child(4),
  .rainbow .g {
       background-color: #2ECE0C;/* green */
    height: 180px;
    width: 380px;
    left: 60px;
  }
  .rainbow p:nth-child(5),
  .rainbow .b {
    background-color: #0000FF; /* blue */
    height: 160px;
    width: 340px;
    left: 80px;
  }
  .rainbow p:nth-child(6),
  .rainbow .i {
       background-color: #6600FF; /* indigo */
    height: 140px;
    width: 300px;
    left: 100px;
  }
  .rainbow p:nth-child(7),
  .rainbow .v {
      background-color: #8B00FF; /* violet */
    height: 120px;
    width: 260px;
    left: 120px;
  }
  .rainbow p:nth-last-of-type(1),
  .rainbow p:last-child {
    background-color: #F9FEFF;
    height: 100px;
    width: 220px;
    left: 140px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="rainbow">
     <p class="r">red</p>
     <p class="o">orange</p>
     <p class="y">yellow</p>
     <p class="g">green</p>
     <p class="b">blue</p>
     <p class="i">indigo</p>
     <p class="v">violet</p>
     <p>the end</p>
 </div>
```

## option 3 (box shadow idea)

```css
div {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 40px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.rainbow {
  background-color: #000;
  display: block;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 80px;
  margin-top: 160px;
  border-radius: 80px;
  box-shadow: 
    0 0 0 20px violet,
    0 0 0 40px indigo,
    0 0 0 60px blue,
    0 0 0 80px green,
    0 0 0 100px yellow,
    0 0 0 120px orange,
    0 0 0 140px red;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="rainbow"></a>
</div>
```

## option 4 (using border colors)

```css
body{
  background: #9ecdef;
}
.rainbow {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;  
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 150px);
  left: calc(50% - 300px);
}
.border{
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-left-color: transparent; 
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.red {
  width: calc(100% - 20px); 
  height: calc(200% - 20px);
  border-top-color: #f00; 
  border-right-color: #f00;
  animation: rotate 2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation: rotate 2s ease-in-out;
  transform: rotate(-45deg); 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.size{
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
}
.orange{
  border-top-color: #ff4500;
  border-right-color: #ff4500;
}
.yellow{
  border-top-color: #ff0;
  border-right-color: #ff0;
}
.green{
  border-top-color: #0f0;
  border-right-color: #0f0;
}
.blue{
  border-top-color: #00f;
  border-right-color: #00f;
}
.cyan{
  border-top-color: #0ff;
  border-right-color: #0ff;
}
.purple{
  border-top-color: #8a2be2;
  border-right-color: #8a2be2;
}
@keyframes rotate { 
  from{-webkit-transform: rotate(-225deg);}
  to{-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from{-webkit-transform: rotate(-225deg);}
  to{-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="rainbow">
  <div class="red border">
    <div class="orange border size">
      <div class="yellow border size">
        <div class="green border size">
          <div class="blue border size">
            <div class="cyan border size">
              <div class="purple border size">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```