# Curved lines using border

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Well, after a little investigation and looking for solutions I've achieved curved lines. But they aren't perfect as I want them .

The desired effect is this:

[image: Desired Effect]

And this is the current effect:

[image: Current Effect]

I'm wondering if someone has a better solution for this or any solution that can achieve the desired effect.

Here's the code :

```css
.left-corner-lines {
      width: 252px;
      float: left;
      min-height: 40px;
      position: relative;
  }
  .left-round-line {
      border-radius: 0 0 0 100%;
      border: 4px solid #fbbc56;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: -4px;
  }
  
  .left-round-line.yellow-round {
      height: 12px;
      width: 17px;
      border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fbbc56;
  }
  
  .left-round-line.blue-round {
      height: 21px;
      width: 26px;
      border-color: transparent transparent transparent #0090d0;
  }
  
  .left-round-line.purple-round {
      height: 30px;
      width: 35px;
      border-color: transparent transparent transparent #915da3;
  }
  
  .left-round-line.pink-round {
      height: 39px;
      width: 44px;
      border-color: transparent transparent transparent #cc5299;
  }
  
  .left-round-line.green-round {
      height: 48px;
      width: 53px;
      border-color: transparent transparent transparent #bed140;
  }
```

```html
<div class="left-corner-lines">
     <div class="left-round-line yellow-round"></div>
     <div class="left-round-line blue-round"></div>
     <div class="left-round-line purple-round"></div>
     <div class="left-round-line pink-round"></div>
     <div class="left-round-line green-round"></div>
</div>
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/84t6w8ca/

The desired effect has to be possible to be recreated for the 4 directions possible.

But I only need one for now since I can recreate the others based on that.

I can do an image fallback for lower versions browsers, so don't worry about `IE8` or less

Has anyone a better solution for this that can achieve it?

### EDIT:

I desire a more rounded corner effect and not so circle ..

What I was thinking is going with `overflow:hidden` square, and placing `divs` inside of it with fixed `border-radius` and bigger in `width` and `height`.

I should also warn you that the line is dynamic depending on content and going around the content till the end of the page. Also, it has lines coming from top and bottom. Like this:

[image: Edit 1]

### EDIT 2:

After @0_o answer I tried to use box-shadows, but you can notice a little blur on it .

Example :

[image: Edit 2]

### EDIT 3:

After using @NileshMahajan I've achieved the following:

[image: Edit 3]

I don't know if it's my eyes going crazy by now, but this is the nearest of what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: Maybe you could look a bit more into svg images or backgrounds.

Comment: Hey there Joel, what do you mean by saying "But they aren't perfect as I want them ." or what is actually your desired effect?  More rounded?

Comment: I tried changing the width and height. They seem more packed together. But I am with @dbd What exactly do you need?

Comment: @dbd I desire a little more rounded-corner effect and not so "curved" .

Comment: do it with box shadows and overflows

Comment: edited the question for a little more explanation . @MathijsSegers about the `svg` , i can't use that because I'm working on top of an old website (not made by me) and they want a new page on top of it..

Comment: If you cant use svg because of browser support, then you cant use box shadows too.

Comment: @JoelAlmeida: Since you say it is a "old" website, I am not sure if this would help you. But still, try and see if the radial gradient approach (with a parent and overflow hidden) mentioned here helps you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730476/css-design-rainbow/27730618#27730618

Comment: @Harry Now OP will complain about jagged lines :v

Comment: @TimKrul I'm just trying to find out the best solution for a perfect line corner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check updated fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/nileshmahaja/84t6w8ca/3/

I have added one container to the entire html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left-corner-lines">
        <div class="left-round-line yellow-round"></div>
        <div class="left-round-line blue-round"></div>
        <div class="left-round-line purple-round"></div>
        <div class="left-round-line pink-round"></div>
        <div class="left-round-line green-round"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

also modified your css code

```
.container{
    position:relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.left-corner-lines {
      width: 200px;
      left: 50%;
      height: 200px;
      position: relative;
      top:-50%
  }
  .left-round-line {
      border-radius:100%;
      border: 5px solid #fbbc56;
      position: absolute;
      left:0;
      right:0;
      top:0;
      bottom:0;
      margin:auto;
  }

  .left-round-line.yellow-round {
      height: 20px;
      width: 20px;
      border-color:#fbbc56;

  }

  .left-round-line.blue-round {
      height: 40px;
      width: 40px;
      border-color: #0090d0;
  }

  .left-round-line.purple-round {
      height: 60px;
      width: 60px;
      border-color: #915da3;
  }

  .left-round-line.pink-round {
      height: 80px;
      width: 80px;
      border-color: #cc5299;
  }

  .left-round-line.green-round {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      border-color: #bed140;
  }
```

Comment: After a little playing around I've almost achieved what I wanted. You can see the result in the edit 3. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

you can also use box-shadow to achieve this

```css
.left-corner-lines {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.left-corner-lines:after {
  content: '';
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  right: 0;
  margin: -15px -15px 0 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px #fbbc56, 0px 0px 0px 10px #fff, 0px 0px 0px 15px #0090d0, 0px 0px 0px 20px #fff, 0px 0px 0px 25px #915da3, 0px 0px 0px 30px #fff, 0px 0px 0px 35px #cc5299;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-corner-lines"></div>
```

Comment: Tried it , but there's a little blur on the lines. Edited post with the image example.

Answer (score 4):

If you want monochromatic lines, you can do that with just one path element in SVG.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="200" height="200" viewBox="4 5 30 30">
  <path d="M5 5 A 25 25 0 0 0 30 30 m0-5 A 20 20 0 0 1 10 5 m5 0 A 15 15 0 0 0 30 20 m0-5 A 10 10 0 0 1 20 5 m5 0 A 5 5 0 0 0 30 10" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
</svg>
```

If you want different coloured segments, its better to use circle elements here.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 30 30">
  <defs>
   <style>
    circle {cx:30; cy:0; stroke-width:2; fill:transparent;}
   </style>
  </defs>
  <circle r="5" stroke="#fbbc56" />
  <circle r="10" stroke="#0090d0" />
  <circle r="15" stroke="#915da3" />
  <circle r="20" stroke="#cc5299" />
  <circle r="25" stroke="#bed140" />
</svg>
```

The advantages of SVG here are :

- **Its short and concise.**
- **Supported on all major browsers** (and IE8+) For IE 8-, you can use VML as a fallback (raphael is a good JS library for this)
- **No blurring or jagging** on all major browsers (as is the case with gradients)
- **Gaps can be transparent** instead of white or solid color. This is achievable using gradients too

Comment: Love the solution! Despite not being able to use this ( current website doesn't allow me to use `svg` tags ). But certainly will take note of this for later.