# How to add small circle into big circle in css3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-shapes

Here is my code for small circle:

```
<div id="circle"></div>

#circle { 
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   background: green; 
   -moz-border-radius: 20px; 
   -webkit-border-radius: 20px; 
   border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Here is jsfiddle link for big circle: http://jsfiddle.net/x1n15791/14/

I need to fit small circle into my big circle at center position.

And after fitting, i need some space between small and big circles.

May i know, how to do that?

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28646858/concentric-circles-with-css)?

Comment: yes @harry. .. but my big circle should have four division,, may i know,, how can i seperated?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ivangrs/x74ce00k/ version using pseudo-elements

Comment: Oh I see @rish. Will vote to re-open then. Do you have an image or something of the shape you wish to achieve?

Comment: @rish I will vote to reopen too but please edit your question with all your requirements (number of divisions, space...). Also, if you had an image/mokup of the desired layout, it would help to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @harry: in my big circle have four part like this http://jsfiddle.net/x1n15791/14/ .. and i need to fit small circle at center position of big circle. thanks.. and i need some space between them.

Comment: @rish the question is getting very unclear. Please make sure you give all the requirements in the first place. As you can see the answers  were made according to the requirements you specified at the biginning. Now that you changed them, they aren't right anymore. This can be very annoying for people who are spending time and effort to help you.

Comment: @web-tiki: here is my final jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/x1n15791/18/ . so may i know, how to fit that small circle in center?

Comment: thanks for all your answers ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The effect of having an inner circle surrounded by an outer circle (which has four sectors) with some space between the inner and outer circle can be achieved using the below mentioned method.

Basically, I have retained the border colors that you had for each border and then added a `height` and `width` to the circle element. This makes the element leave a circular area in the middle inside the separated borders. Within the inner circular area another circle is added using the inset `box-shadow` technique mentioned in both the post that I linked earlier.

```css
#circle {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 40px solid black;
  border-top: 40px solid black;
  border-left: 40px solid green;
  border-right: 40px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blue;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 10px white;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```

> **Note for Future readers:** This may not be the best depending on your needs because the inner circle is produced using box-shadow. So for instance, if you want an image inside it then this approach would not work.
>
> Similarly if you want the four separated areas on around the circle to be clickable with different actions then also this approach will not work.

Comment: so how to do, the four separated areas on around the circle to be clickable with different actions? further i need this one. @harry: can you please help me? thanks

Comment: For that you need different elements @rish

Comment: That is not  bother me @harry: can you please show any sample ?

Comment: @rish: I would recommend you to have a look at both chipChocolate.py's answer and ThePragmatick's answer in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27943053/how-to-create-a-circle-with-links-on-border-side/27944020#27944020). Your needs seem to be almost same.

Comment: @Harry: can you please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28718697/how-to-change-the-size-of-circle-in-svg

Answer (score 2):

Here is a 100% pure css example:

This works perfectly:

```css
#circle, #circle:before, #circle:after {
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 display: block;
}

#circle:before, #circle:after {
 position: relative;
 content: '';
}

#circle { 
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: white;
 border: 20px solid blue;
}

#circle:before {
 width: 50%;
 height: 50%;
 top: 25%;
 left: 25%;
 background: red;
}

#circle:after {
 width: 20%;
 height: 20%;
 top: -10%;
 left: 40%;
 background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```

This works even with IE8!

If you need to set a different size, change the `width` and `height` of the `#circle`.

You can set more by playing with borders on the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements.

Also notice that this will work in browsers who don't support `border-radius`, but will display as a square.

The central dot may need some adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.circle { 
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;

   -moz-border-radius: 50%; 
   -webkit-border-radius: 50%; 
   border-radius: 50%;

  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;   
  box-sizing: border-box;       
}

.circle.one{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  background:#440000;
  padding:40px;
}

.circle.two{
  background:#662222;
    padding:80px;
}
.circle.three{
  background:#884444;
    padding:20px;
}
.circle.four{
  background:#ff8888;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle one">  
    <div class="circle two">
      <div class="circle three">
        <div class="circle four">
        </div> 
      </div> 
    </div>  
</div>
```

[image: screen shot]

Comment: i need some space between these circles.. and i need four division like my posted jsfiddle.

Comment: @rish, please edit your question and post an image of what should be the expected result

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full CSS solution, which requires no extra markup:

```css
#circle { 
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: green; 
}
#circle,
#circle:before,
#circle:after {
  -moz-border-radius: 100%; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%; 
  border-radius: 100%;
}
#circle:before,
#circle:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#circle:before {
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  background: white; 
}
#circle:after {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: yellow; 
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just with CSS you can achieve it easily :

```
#circle { 


 width: 400px;
   height: 400px;
   background: green; 
   -moz-border-radius: 200px; 
   -webkit-border-radius: 200px; 
   border-radius: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
#circle:before{
    display: block;
    content: '';
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: white; 
    -moz-border-radius: 50px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px; 
    border-radius: 50px;    
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x1n15791/17/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple and pure CSS solution that uses the **border** and **box-shadow** properties

```css
.circle
{
  height:70px;
  width:70px;
  background-color:red;
  border:24px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 24px blue;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure CSS solution:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="circle">
      <div id="small-circle">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

#circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color:green;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#small-circle{
  margin-top: 25%;
  margin-left: 24%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 45%;
  height: 45%;
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
  border-radius: 50%;   
  border:10px solid black;
}
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/RV5b4/228/

Comment: It's not a full CSS solution, it requires extra markup.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
#circle:after;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/johanthuresson/x1n15791/23/