# How to get border with some space?

Tags: css

How to get border with some space?  Just like-

[image]

[image]

Comment: You actually don't need any extra elements or outline etc. Plain borders with some padding and `background-clip` is more than enough. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/nhh7Ldqt/) is a sample. Not adding an answer because I remember a similar question earlier.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28646858/concentric-circles-with-css/28647073#28647073) is the question that I was referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Use outline property:

```
outline: 2px solid red;
outline-offset: 3px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Outline alone is not enough, if no border is present.

But you could set the border to match your respecitve background color:

```
#test{
  background: red;
  border: 2px solid white;
  outline: 2px solid red;    
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dntbn733/

---

For round corners you could wrap some divs to achieve the same:

```
.red{
    background-color:red;
    padding:2px;
    border-radius:10px;
}

.white {
    background-color:white;
    padding:2px;
    border-radius:10px;
}

<div class="red">
    <div class="white">
        <div class="red">        
            test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dteqogos/

Comment: Try rounding the border on the div and see what happens.

Comment: @j08691 The tc asks for "border with space" - not "border with space and round corners" :)

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by simply using CSS `:before` or `:after` selectors.

```css
#borderer {
  background: red;
  border: 10px solid white; 
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  line-height: 140px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 88px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: calibri;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

#borderer:after {
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: '';
  left: -15px;
  top: -15px;
  z-index: -1;
  
  }
```

```html
<div id="borderer">

2
</div>
```