# How to draw a responsive shape

Tags: jquery, css, svg, responsive-design, css-shapes

**Back story/context:**
I'm doing a child activity in which the child will hear a sound and decide on what colour to use to paint a section of a catterpillar body.
This has to be responsive. I'm using just HTML, CSS and Javascript. Bootstrap is taking care of my responsive side, and I'm using measures in %'s or vmin/vmax...
I need to be able to address each section of the body separately, so I can colour it according to choices made by the user!

**So far:**
I tried using a div with 20 divs inside, each for a section with an image for each section and I tried drawing them with CSS; I also tried the first approach with just one div and everything inside...

**The Problem:**
All the solutions so far fail when I resize my window. I tried position as absolute, as relative, ...

**So**: I need to position up to 20 circles, CSS or SVG (preferably), that can be addressed each on its own by an user interaction (click on it to change colour), and that maintain their shape when you resize the window.

Below I'm putting an image of the catterpillar I would like to recreate in html:

[image: Catterpilar]

Any hints, directions or how-to's will help. Or if you have any other view on how to solve this...

Cheers!

Comment: what happens when you resize the window? could you show your attempts please?

Comment: For this specific image the solution may be simple. The question is: do you also want to paint other images?

Comment: Thanks @web-tiki for adding my image!

FabrizioCalderan - sorry I didn't kept any images of the previous attempts. I would try something, test out and move on... What I can tell you is that the circles (or png's) would switch places. Imagine I had something like this : d0000X (being X the head and d the tail) and I could end up having: d00
                                    0x0... or x on top of other elements and so on...
skobaljic - I just want to paint that image. But, that image cant be a single png... I need to access the different sections of the body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There can be several approaches to make your catterpillar responsive. You could use svg, multiple elements/pseudo elements, box-shadows...

Here is an example using multiple [box shadows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) and the appraoch described here : [Overlapping circles in CSS with 1 div](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27314411/1811992) using the second example with viewport related units :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/n6Ltqqta/)**

```css
div{
  width:20vmin; height:20vmin;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:gold;
  margin:0 auto;
  box-shadow: -10vmin   1vmin  0  .2vmin teal,
              -18vmin  .5vmin  0   1vmin pink,
              -25vmin  .8vmin  0  .5vmin tomato,
              -37vmin   1vmin  0  .2vmin green,
              -50vmin   1vmin  0  .5vmin teal,
              -63vmin   1vmin  0  .2vmin aqua;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

And here is an example using an [svg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG) with the circle element :

```css
svg{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 20">
    <circle cx="35" cy="10" r="4" fill="green" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5" />
    <circle cx="40" cy="9" r="5.1" fill="teal" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5" />
    <circle cx="46" cy="11" r="5" fill="pink" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="10" r="4" fill="tomato" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5" />    
</svg>
```

Comment: very elegant solution, though I'm quite sure there will be problems with IE

Comment: @MarioA thx. Regarding IE, box-shadows are supported by IE9 and over.

Comment: I was going to post the box-shadow one :O Nice any way! +1)

Comment: I ended up using svg! Box shadow looks really cool but I didn't understood how to address each "shadow" on its own! And I need to be able to click and change each one! Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to color circle shapes, we can use DIV elements with border-radius 50%. You can keep everything in percents, even to simulate the circles border width this way:

```js
var circles = [
    {
        left: 5,
        top: 5,
        radius: 5
    },
    {
        left: 7.5,
        top: 7,
        radius: 8
    },
    {
        left: 11.5,
        top: 10,
        radius: 8
    },
    {
        left: 14.5,
        top: 14,
        radius: 9
    }
];
var wormBox = $('.worm');
$.each(circles, function(i, data) {
    var circle = $('<div class="circle"><div class="color"></div></div>');
    circle.css({
        'width': data.radius+'%',
        'padding-bottom': data.radius+'%',
        'left': data.left+'%',
        'top': data.top+'%'
    });
    circle.appendTo( wormBox );
});
$('.color').on('click', function(e) {
   // Test color with random
    var randomColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    $(this).css({
        'background-color': randomColor
    });
});
```

```css
.worm {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.circle {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: none #000;
}
.color {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3%;
    right: 3%;
    bottom: 3%;
    left: 3%;
    width: 94%;
    background: none #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="worm"></div>
```

Resizing the browser width will resize all elements inside `.worm`. Clicking the circles will add random background color.

Please note: I used script, but the result is pure HTML/CSS (you need script only for coloring).

Another note: since you use pure html, than you can also animate your worm.

Same script is also on **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69gts69j/)**.

Comment: Cool! I like the idea of animating it. I hadn't planned for it but maybe I can do it to tweak the positions so every time a user goes to that page the caterpillar is slightly different! Cheers man!

Comment: I wanted to make it that way, but have no time today.. maybe tomorrow. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Your approch with images and absolute positioning could work, but use percentage values for the `left` property:

http://jsfiddle.net/0dea7r75/

```
<div class="catterpillar">
    <img src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/circle-clip-art-yToeE5KLc.png" class="cirlce c1" />
    <img src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/circle-clip-art-yToeE5KLc.png" class="cirlce c2" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.catterpillar {
    width: 50%; // use a percantage for the width of the catterpillar
    position:relative;
}

.cirlce {
    position:absolute;
}

.c1 {
    width:5%; // use percentage for width and left
    left: 0%;
    top: 0;
}

.c2 {
    width:8%; 
    left: 3%;
    top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you web-tiki and Mario A. I'm going to try out both approaches by today and tomorrow and accept one. 
Also thanks for alerting me to the other post!
Mario A could you please elaborate on why using percent  for my left values other than vmin or vmax?
Thanks again!